# How can one select the 'systemd-boot' bootloader over 'GRUB' when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, systemd-boot

How can one select the 'systemd-boot' bootloader over 'GRUB' when installing Ubuntu?

There are methods for installing systemd-boot after the initial installation, but residual GRUB components may persist, potentially causing issues when Ubuntu eventually performs a GRUB upgrade (while it's not the bootloader - I asked a question about this as well a while ago).

Comment: the now older Ubiquity installer used with 22.04 and before and some flavors could do this: 
This launches the installer program (Ubiquity) with an option (-b) to not install a boot loader from live installer in live mode:
In the Terminal window, type ubiquity -b. You will probably need a larger ESP and know how to boot & install systemd boot separately.

Comment: Thanks. I actually installed systemd-boot on my current system after the initial install, but it's hard (impossible?) to get rid of grub completely after it's been installed - too many dependencies.